# Fetching Video(Mp4 format) Using Axios in React and displaying in HTML video

Tags: reactjs, axios, video-streaming, html5-video, blob

I was trying to fetch a video from backend in the form of byte stream and i was able to get video from backend. But i am unable to handle the video on front end using axios. My code was some thing like

```
const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
         axios.get(/pathToVideo, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'video/mp4;charset=UTF-8'
                },
            }).then({
        const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: "video/mp4"}));
        setVideo(url);
        })
})
```

and my HTML looks like

```
            <video controls autoPlay loop muted>
                <source src={video} type="video/mp4"></source>
            </video>
```

The blob is creating some link but that link contains nothing, can some one suggest me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you get the video path to the server? and add that as source?

Comment: Yes that idea works but our requirement needs the video to be fetched to be front end

Comment: The backend should then return the video's source url as a string and you should add it

Answer (score 1):

Add this under your header to make this:

```
headers: {
    Accept: 'video/mp4;charset=UTF-8'
},
responseType: 'blob'
```

responseType is very important

Comment: Thanks! I was using Axios and the 'responseType' was exactly what was missing for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't use React-JS or Axios but from experience with blobs I would try something like this...

1. Set your HTML first so the axios response code finds the video tag (it has empty `.src`):

```
<video id="vidObj" width="500" height="360" controls loop muted autoplay>
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

2. Then afterwards you can add your script somewhere as:

```
    useEffect( () => {
    axios.get( pathToVideo, { headers: { Accept: 'video/mp4;charset=UTF-8' } } )
    .then( response => {
            myUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( new Blob([response.data]) ); // response.data.data
            
            var myVid = document.getElementById('vidObj');
            myVid.setAttribute("src", myUrl);
            myVid.play(); //# test playback
            
            //setVideo(url); //# is this needed?
        })
    });
```

The above is untested but hope it helps somehow.

Notes:

- Does React expect `/pathToVideo` instead of just `pathToVideo`? 
  *(where `pathToVideo = "https://somelink.etc";`)*
- If `response.data` does not work, maybe try as `response.data.data`.
- I'm not sure what `source src={video}` does but if possible make `.src` empty so it's later updated by the axios blob response.

Answer (score 0):

return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.arrayBuffer());

Comment: The question is clearly asking about `axios` not `fetch`.